# I am having problem sorting custom post type using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, sort

I have a custom post type called personnel

Look at this code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'personnel', 
               'posts_per_page' => -1,  
              );
$personnel_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Above works fine but I wanted the posts to be sorted alphabetically. I tried this:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'personnel', 
               'posts_per_page' => -1,  
               'orderby' => 'title', 
               'order' => 'ASC'
              );
$personnel_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But it doesn't have any effect on the sorting. I tried both ASC and DESC for the order-attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If there's an error - I'm not seeing it, looks correct to me. Are you sure you're not cached?

Comment: I just figured it out. It's a plugin called Post Types Order that is ovverriding the WP_Query functionality somehow which makes the admin able to sort different post/categories etc.

Comment: You should post this as an answer, so this question doesn't go unanswered for eternity!

Comment: done. I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer though...

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else happens to stumble upon an issue like this:

I'm using a plugin called Post Types Order (https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/) that is somehow "overriding" the sorting-mechanism of WP_Query.